# How do I delete the 'offline' directory created by dism?

Tags: windows, dism

While creating a slipstreamed Windows ISO, I wanted to 'un-do' and start over with a better plan. I attempted to delete the workspace but the workspace had a directory called `offline`, created by dism, with several GB worth of files owned by `System` and therefore could not deleted, giving an `access is denied` error. Some files involved were `offline\Windows\mib.bin` and several .DLLs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Run (as administrator) `DISM /cleanup-wim`

Expect this to delete the contents of the offline directory, even if the image is corrupt, incomplete or unmounted.

ref: [Can’t Delete...Folder After Failed Servicing](https://sccm2012.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/cant-delete-configmgr_offlineimageservicing-folder-after-failed-servicing/)